# PostgreSQL JDBC Driver returns 1111 type for literals in query

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I've faced a problem with PostgreSQL JDBC Driver. I created a simple table with one column, added three rows and queried it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=user&password=password");

            Statement Stmt = Conn.createStatement();
            String sqlCommand = "select id, 'ff' from testable";

            ResultSet RS = Stmt.executeQuery(sqlCommand);
            final ResultSetMetaData meta = RS.getMetaData();

            while (RS.next()) {
                System.out.println(meta.getColumnType(2)+ " " +RS.getString(2));
            }
            // Clean up after ourselves
            RS.close();
            Stmt.close();
            Conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException E) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + E.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState:     " + E.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError:  " + E.getErrorCode());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The output is:

```
1111 ff
1111 ff
1111 ff
```

PostgreSQL JDBC Driver returns 1111 metadata code which corresponds java.sql.Types.OTHER, not a VARCHAR(which code is 12).
For example, same script for MySQL driver returns:

```
12 ff
12 ff
12 ff
```

My question is - why PostgreSQL returns Types.OTHER for literals? Is any way to get types correctly in all common JDBC drivers(mysql,postgre,mssql,oracle)?

Driver version is 9.4.1208.jre7.

Comment: Because literals in Postgres *aren't* `varchar`. Literals can represent arrays, timestamps, JSON documents, or a hundred other things depending on the context. The default type given to a bare literal (or a bare `NULL`) is called `unknown`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a PgJDBC issue, when you use a literal like that:

```
select id, 'ff' from testable
```

For PostgreSQL is an *unknown* type, so it maps to Types.OTHER, if your really want to handle it as a *varchar*, you should cast it:

```
select id, 'ff'::varchar from testable
```

**UPDATE:** PostgreSQL 10 changed this behavior, now it returns the text OID, which maps to *Types.VARCHAR*.